R adding list to a list and different data type to that list in a list
I want to make a list that represents rows to print; a row contains text and numeric data; I make a toplist that contains for each row a list to print.
The list for rows are constructed from stat.desc output the first 'word' on the row is text then followed by numerical values. topList[1]  is a column header line
Two problems arrise with adding things to lists
a) adding a list (with a couple of components) to a topList gives unexpected warning and results
b) adding a numerical to a list with text components converts the numerical to text
Eventually the desired output should look like
  ident age income
nbr.val 55 10,000.00
nbr.null 0 0
...

The basic two problems that I have extracted from the  R functions that I am producing, is described in the script below.

adding a list to the topList (e.g. the header line)
adding a component of different type to a list in the topList

topList<-list()
topList[1]<-list("ident", "age", "income") # add first component (a list w headers) to toplist
# Warning message:
# In t[1] <- list("ident", "age", "income") :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
# I was expecting to be able to add a list (with 3 components) to topList on its 1st position

# try a different way
topList<-list()
topList[1]<- list("ident") # add a list with just one component
class(topList[1])   # yields "list" as expected
topList[1]          # yields "ident" a list with one component;
class(topList[[1]]) # yields "character" we are addressing the content of the list; NOT expected
                    # as the content of the list can contain various data types
toplist[[1]]        # yields "ident" the content of the list as class is character
topList[[1]][1]     # yields "ident"  the 1st component of components in the list
                    # do we have a list in the 1st position of the topList ????
        

# add a new component to the header row
topList[[1]][2]<-"age"
topList[1]          # yields 
                    # [[1]]
                    # [1] "ident" "age"  as expected: 2 components
length(topList)     # yields 1 as expected 1 list (row) is in the topList
length(topList[1])  # yields 1 as there is one list in the first position of topList
length(topList[[1]])# yields 2, the list in the first position contains two components

# now add a numerical value to the list in the 1st position of topList
topList[[1]][3]<-3.21
topList             # yields
                    # [[1]]
                    # [1] "ident" "age"  "3.21"  (3 components are expected, but "3.21 NOT)
                    # I was expecting 3.21 to be numerical
class(t[[1]])       # yields stil "character" NOT expected


Can you make your question clearer, as I am struggling to understand exactly what you need help with.

Do you simply want topList[[1]]<-list("ident", "age", "income")? Your question reads like an xy problem.

Read help("[").

If it's about constructing a nested list, step-by-step, then you should pay closer attention to [] vs [[]].
Let's start by creating a reference structure, in one go:
lst_ref <- list(
  list("ident", "age", "income"),
  list("nbr.val", 55, 10000.00),
  list("nbr.null", 0, 0)
)
str(lst_ref)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : chr "ident"
#>   ..$ : chr "age"
#>   ..$ : chr "income"
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : chr "nbr.val"
#>   ..$ : num 55
#>   ..$ : num 10000
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : chr "nbr.null"
#>   ..$ : num 0
#>   ..$ : num 0

And now let's try to replicate it, step-by-step:
lst_repl <- list()
lst_repl[[1]] <- list()
lst_repl[[1]][[1]] <- "ident"
lst_repl[[1]][[2]] <- "age"
lst_repl[[1]][[3]] <- "income"

lst_repl[[2]] <- list()
lst_repl[[2]][[1]] <- "nbr.val"
lst_repl[[2]][[2]] <- 55
lst_repl[[2]][[3]] <- 10000.00

lst_repl[[3]] <- list()
lst_repl[[3]][[1]] <- "nbr.null"
lst_repl[[3]][[2]] <- 0
lst_repl[[3]][[3]] <- 0

str(lst_repl)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : chr "ident"
#>   ..$ : chr "age"
#>   ..$ : chr "income"
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : chr "nbr.val"
#>   ..$ : num 55
#>   ..$ : num 10000
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : chr "nbr.null"
#>   ..$ : num 0
#>   ..$ : num 0

Are those nested lists indeed identical?
identical(lst_ref, lst_repl)
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2024-06-10 with reprex v2.1.0

The answer is fine, the [] vs [[]] is indeed my problem; I was not expecting list elements to address with [[]]; will look into it as suggested

@BenJ [ subsets the list (it returns a list). [[ extracts an element of a list (it returns whatever type of object the list contains).
